# Prevent React from capturing tab character

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have an input field. I want React to check if a tab has been pressed in this field. If so, then process the contents of that field (e.g. ajax call).

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return { name: "" }; 
},

handleChangeName: function(e) {
  this.setState({name: e.target.value});
},

handleKeyUp: function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Execute ajax call after tab pressed");
  }
},

<input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChangeName}
   onKeyDown={this.handleKeyUp} />
```

Problem:

Tab keypress is intercepted and subsequent code executed but **the tab character is inserted into the input text field**. How do I prevent this from happening?

I have tried various combinations of `preventDefault`, `stopPropagation`, `stopImmediatePropagation`. I can get a result of no further chars being inserted into the input text field, but then no subsequent code is executed.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered using the `onBlur` event? Since this will also capture the user navigating out of the field via some other method, and more closely matches what you're trying to do

Comment: Rather than doing these, why you not call a method on onBlur event.

Comment: Thanks. I think that I actually want it as a key press, UX-wise, rather than navigating off via some other method. But good suggestion.

Comment: The way to prevent the input from happening is to have your event handler return `false` for that key input.

Answer (score 22):

The events **onKeyUp** or **onKeyPress** won't be called when '**Tab**' is pressed because it triggers a **onBlur** before, you need to catch it with **onKeyDown**. You can try to use the event **key** instead of **keyCode**, as the example above.

function:

```
 handleKeyDown: function(e) {
    if (e.key === "Tab") {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Execute ajax call after tab pressed");
    }
  }
```

input:

```
<input type="text" onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} />
```

I hope it helps ;).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's somehow connected with the fact that you pass both onChange and onKeyDown handlers.

I think you have following options:

1. Try to change order of these handlers: onKeyDown - first, onChange - second. I am not sure that would help.

```js
<input type="text" value={this.state.name} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyUp} onChange={this.handleChangeName} />
```

2. You can handle both cases in the single handler like onKeyDown or onKeyPress.

```js
handleKeyPress(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return alert('hey ho lets go');
  }

  this.setState({name: e.target.value});  
}
```