# how to capture tab key press in react component?

Tags: reactjs

I've wired up an onKeyPress event handler for an input in a React component.  The event handler is capturing the key that is pressed.  For example, if the letter A is pressed then event.key = "A", if the number 2 is pressed then event.key = "2"

However, when focus is inside the input and I press the Tab key, the onKeyPress event is not triggered for that input.  The tab keypress simply advances focus to the next field.  But I'm specifically trying to capture that event.  Any idea how I can wire up my component to make that happen?

Comment: Use onKeyDown instead

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but the answer is still relevant: [Prevent React from capturing tab character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888205/prevent-react-from-capturing-tab-character)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` and prevent the default behaviour of `Tab` key:

```
export default function App() {
  const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Tab") {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("Tab");
    }
  };
  return <input onKeyDown={onKeyDown} />;
}
```

[image: Edit strange-christian-jtngc]